netty issues after update spring boot version from 3.2.0 to 3.3.0
application runs on macos
exception thrown in runtime
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception with message: 'io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.socketChannelFactory(io.netty.channel.ChannelFactory, boolean)'
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.socketChannelFactory(io.netty.channel.ChannelFactory, boolean)'
my client config

        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
                .keyManager(clientCertificateHandler.keyManagerFactory())
                .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                .ciphers(Http2SecurityUtil.CIPHERS, SupportedCipherSuiteFilter.INSTANCE)
                .applicationProtocolConfig(
                        new ApplicationProtocolConfig(ApplicationProtocolConfig.Protocol.ALPN, ApplicationProtocolConfig.SelectorFailureBehavior.NO_ADVERTISE,
                                ApplicationProtocolConfig.SelectedListenerFailureBehavior.ACCEPT, ApplicationProtocolNames.HTTP_2))
                .build();

        var provider = ConnectionProvider
                .builder("app-provider")
                .maxConnections(500)
                .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(45))
                .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(600)).build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.
                create(provider)
                .secure(sslContextSpec -> {
                    sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext)
                            .handlerConfigurator(sslHandler -> {
                                SSLEngine engine = sslHandler.engine();
                                SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
                                List<SNIMatcher> matchers = new LinkedList<>();
                                SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                };
                                matchers.add(matcher);
                                params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
                                engine.setSSLParameters(params);
                            });
                })
                .runOn(reactorResourceFactory.getLoopResources())
                .compress(true)
                .keepAlive(true)
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000)
                .option(EpollChannelOption.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 300)
                .option(EpollChannelOption.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 60)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
                .protocol(HttpProtocol.H2)
                .baseUrl(ssoServiceUrl)
                .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                        .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                        .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                ;


        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .baseUrl(ssoServiceUrl)
                .filter(modifyRequestHeaders(new LinkedMultiValueMap<>()))
                .filter((request, exchangeFunction) -> {
                    return exchangeFunction
                            .exchange(request).doOnNext(resp -> {
                        var responseCookies = resp.cookies();
                        if (responseCookies.containsKey(ACCESS_KEY_COOKIE)) {
                            tokenHolder.updateAccessToken(responseCookies.get(ACCESS_KEY_COOKIE).get(0).getValue());
                        }
                    });
                })
                .build();

my pom
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>kz.aitups.sso.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>webflux</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-kqueue</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.version}</version>
            <classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>

<!--         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.tcnative.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-tcnative -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.tcnative.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



i'v tried to change defautl netty version from 4.1.60.Final
but nothing helps

This exception suggests that you have mismatch of the Netty versions, if you use the dependencies collected by Spring Boot, then something else brings an older Netty version

need some formatting

@VioletaGeorgieva thanks, finally l'v found netty.version tag in my pom which was added to another dependency (tcnative, boringssl), and after i'v removed the tag app started normally
